# Error on read external .msg file and parse it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [library](https://github.com/ykarpovich/msg.reader) in order to read `.msg` file. That is working fine but I want to use external url .msg file.

In library they are using input type file to get file:

```
var selectedFile = this.files[0];
```

I am want to get file from url so my code is:

```
 <script>
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", "https://www.example.net/1564221393.msg", true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var blob = oReq.response;
        blob.name = "lead-100-1564221393.msg";
    }
    oReq.send();

    var selectedFile = blob;
</script>
```

I am want to save file to variable `selectedFile` therefore I can use same code after that.

**Please see below complete code:**

```js
function isSupportedFileAPI() {
  return window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob;
}

function formatEmail(data) {
  return data.name ? data.name + " [" + data.email + "]" : data.email;
}

function parseHeaders(headers) {
  var parsedHeaders = {};
  if (!headers) {
    return parsedHeaders;
  }
  var headerRegEx = /(.*)\: (.*)/g;
  while (m = headerRegEx.exec(headers)) {
    // todo: Pay attention! Header can be presented many times (e.g. Received). Handle it, if needed!
    parsedHeaders[m[1]] = m[2];
  }
  return parsedHeaders;
}

function getMsgDate(rawHeaders) {
  // Example for the Date header
  var headers = parseHeaders(rawHeaders);
  if (!headers['Date']) {
    return '-';
  }
  return new Date(headers['Date']);
}

$(function() {
  if (isSupportedFileAPI()) {
    $('#verifyIt').click(function() {
      ///// Read external file /////

      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.open("GET", "https://itcoinbay.lasthash.com/10e9651b698fb705c57195d112f40678-1563518398.msg", true);
      oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var blob = oReq.response;
        blob.name = "10e9651b698fb705c57195d112f40678-1563518398.msg";

        // Put your line here, you can use blob directly
        var selectedFile = blob;
      }
      oReq.send();

      if (!selectedFile) {
        $('.msg-info, .incorrect-type').hide();
        return;
      }
      if (selectedFile.name.indexOf('.msg') == -1) {
        $('.msg-info').hide();
        $('.incorrect-type').show();
        return;
      }
      $('.msg-example .msg-file-name').html(selectedFile.name);
      $('.incorrect-type').hide();

      // read file...
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(evt) {

        var buffer = evt.target.result;
        var msgReader = new MSGReader(buffer);
        var fileData = msgReader.getFileData();
        if (!fileData.error) {
          $('.msg-example .msg-from').html(formatEmail({
            name: fileData.senderName,
            email: fileData.senderEmail
          }));

          $('.msg-example .msg-to').html(jQuery.map(fileData.recipients, function(recipient, i) {
            return formatEmail(recipient);
          }).join('<br/>'));
          $('.msg-example .msg-date').html(getMsgDate(fileData.headers));
          $('.msg-example .msg-subject').html(fileData.subject);
          $('.msg-example .msg-body').html(
            fileData.body ? fileData.body.substring(0, Math.min(500, fileData.body.length)) +
            (fileData.body.length > 500 ? '...' : '') : '');
          if (fileData.bodyHTML) {
            $('.msg-example .msg-body-html').html(fileData.bodyHTML).closest('div.field-block').show();
          } else {
            $('.msg-example .msg-body-html').closest('div.field-block').hide();
          }
          $('.msg-example .msg-attachment').html(jQuery.map(fileData.attachments, function(attachment, i) {
            var file = msgReader.getAttachment(i);
            var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new File([file.content], attachment.fileName, {
              type: attachment.mimeType ? attachment.mimeType : "application/octet-stream"
            }));
            return attachment.fileName + ' [' + attachment.contentLength + 'bytes]' +
              (attachment.pidContentId ? '; ID = ' + attachment.pidContentId : '') +
              '; <a href="' + fileUrl + '">Download</a>';
          }).join('<br/>'));
          $('.msg-info').show();

          // Use msgReader.getAttachment to access attachment content ...
          // msgReader.getAttachment(0) or msgReader.getAttachment(fileData.attachments[0])
        } else {
          $('.msg-info').hide();
          $('.incorrect-type').show();
        }
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
    });
  } else {
    $('.msg-example').hide();
    $('.file-api-not-available').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://crm.primalead.com/public/js/DataStream.js"></script>
 <script src="https://crm.primalead.com/public/js/msg.reader.js"></script>
 <button id="verifyIt">Verify It</button>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="msg-info" style="display: none;">
    <div class="info-box wizard-msg">
      2. MSG info (<span class="msg-file-name"></span>)
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">From</div>
      <div class="msg-from"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">To</div>
      <div class="msg-to"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Date (from Headers, example)</div>
      <div class="msg-date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Subject</div>
      <div class="msg-subject"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Body</div>
      <div class="msg-body"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block" style="display: none;">
      <div class="field-label">HTML Body</div>
      <div class="msg-body-html"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Attachments</div>
      <div class="msg-attachment"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="incorrect-type info-box error-msg" style="display: none;">
    Sorry, the file you selected is not MSG type
  </div>

  <div class="file-api-not-available info-box error-msg" style="display: none;">
    Sorry, your browser isn't supported
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `var selectedFile = blob;` should be inside the callback function, if you put it like you did, you should receive `undefined` since the callback wouldn't be executed yet. It executes once received the response from Ajax.

```
<script>
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", "https://www.example.net/1564221393.msg", true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var blob = oReq.response;
        blob.name = "lead-100-1564221393.msg";

        // Put your line here, you can use blob directly
        var selectedFile = blob;
    }
    oReq.send();

    // Here blob isn't known at all, since it is defined inside
    // the above function using var, so it is only known inside it
    // plus the function executes only after some miliseconds the time
    // for the response to return from https://www.example.net/
    var selectedFile = blob;
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a working code after I corrected a couple of things

```js
function isSupportedFileAPI() {
  return window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob;
}

function formatEmail(data) {
  return data.name ? data.name + " [" + data.email + "]" : data.email;
}

function parseHeaders(headers) {
  var parsedHeaders = {};
  if (!headers) {
    return parsedHeaders;
  }
  var headerRegEx = /(.*)\: (.*)/g;
  while (m = headerRegEx.exec(headers)) {
    // todo: Pay attention! Header can be presented many times (e.g. Received). Handle it, if needed!
    parsedHeaders[m[1]] = m[2];
  }
  return parsedHeaders;
}

function getMsgDate(rawHeaders) {
  // Example for the Date header
  var headers = parseHeaders(rawHeaders);
  if (!headers['Date']) {
    return '-';
  }
  return headers['Date'];
}

$(function() {
  if (isSupportedFileAPI()) {
    $('#verifyIt').click(function() {
      ///// Read external file /////

      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.open("GET", "https://itcoinbay.lasthash.com/10e9651b698fb705c57195d112f40678-1563518398.msg", true);
      oReq.responseType = "blob";
      oReq.onload = onSuccess;
      oReq.send();

      function onSuccess(oEvent) {
        var selectedFile = oReq.response;
        selectedFile.name = "10e9651b698fb705c57195d112f40678-1563518398.msg";

        if (!selectedFile) {
          $('.msg-info, .incorrect-type').hide();
          return;
        }
        if (selectedFile.name.indexOf('.msg') == -1) {
          $('.msg-info').hide();
          $('.incorrect-type').show();
          return;
        }
        $('.msg-example .msg-file-name').html(selectedFile.name);
        $('.incorrect-type').hide();

        // read file...
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(evt) {

          var buffer = evt.target.result;
          var msgReader = new MSGReader(buffer);
          var fileData = msgReader.getFileData();
          if (!fileData.error) {
            $('.msg-example .msg-from').html(formatEmail({
              name: fileData.senderName,
              email: fileData.senderEmail
            }));

            $('.msg-example .msg-to').html(jQuery.map(fileData.recipients, function(recipient, i) {
              return formatEmail(recipient);
            }).join('<br/>'));
            $('.msg-example .msg-date').html(getMsgDate(fileData.headers));
            $('.msg-example .msg-subject').html(fileData.subject);
            $('.msg-example .msg-body').html(
              fileData.body ? fileData.body.substring(0, Math.min(500, fileData.body.length)) +
              (fileData.body.length > 500 ? '...' : '') : '');
            if (fileData.bodyHTML) {
              $('.msg-example .msg-body-html').html(fileData.bodyHTML).parent().show();
            } else {
              $('.msg-example .msg-body-html').parent().hide();
            }
            $('.msg-example .msg-attachment').html(jQuery.map(fileData.attachments, function(attachment, i) {
              var file = msgReader.getAttachment(i);
              var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new File([file.content], attachment.fileName, {
                type: attachment.mimeType ? attachment.mimeType : "application/octet-stream"
              }));
              return attachment.fileName + ' [' + attachment.contentLength + 'bytes]' +
                (attachment.pidContentId ? '; ID = ' + attachment.pidContentId : '') +
                '; <a href="' + fileUrl + '">Download</a>';
            }).join('<br/>'));
            $('.msg-info').show();

            // Use msgReader.getAttachment to access attachment content ...
            // msgReader.getAttachment(0) or msgReader.getAttachment(fileData.attachments[0])
          } else {
            $('.msg-info').hide();
            $('.incorrect-type').show();
          }
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.msg-example').hide();
    $('.file-api-not-available').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://crm.primalead.com/public/js/DataStream.js"></script>
<script src="https://crm.primalead.com/public/js/msg.reader.js"></script>
<button id="verifyIt">Verify It</button>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="msg-info msg-example" style="display: none;">
    <div class="info-box wizard-msg">
      2. MSG info (<span class="msg-file-name"></span>)
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">From</div>
      <div class="msg-from"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">To</div>
      <div class="msg-to"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Date (from Headers, example)</div>
      <div class="msg-date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Subject</div>
      <div class="msg-subject"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Body</div>
      <div class="msg-body"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block" style="display: none;">
      <div class="field-label">HTML Body</div>
      <div class="msg-body-html"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-block">
      <div class="field-label">Attachments</div>
      <div class="msg-attachment"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="incorrect-type info-box error-msg" style="display: none;">
    Sorry, the file you selected is not MSG type
  </div>

  <div class="file-api-not-available info-box error-msg" style="display: none;">
    Sorry, your browser isn't supported
  </div>
</div>
```

Below are the corrections:

1- Wrapped most of the code into a function which I named `onSuccess`, it is put as the callback to Ajax response, this is necessary as I explained above.

2- Changed `oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";` to `oReq.responseType = "blob";`. As noted by @krukid answer.

3- Changed `<div class="msg-info" style="display: none;">` to `<div class="msg-info msg-example" style="display: none;">`. You used the `msg-example` css class in the js but forgot it in the html.

4- Changed `$('.msg-example .msg-body-html').html(fileData.bodyHTML).closest('div.field-block').show();` to `$('.msg-example .msg-body-html').html(fileData.bodyHTML).parent().show();`. Weirdly the jquery function `closest` isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for answer but still not working, you can see this : js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/shivsingh7150/eL36bayg/15/

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

1. As @ankabout has pointed out, `blob` variable is referenced in the wrong scope. I assume this is a typo.
2. Secondly, what you get in a XHR response is not a `Blob` at all. Your requested type is `arraybuffer`.

I suspect (2) is your main issue, since the example page for your library operates with `Blob`/`File` objects, not `ArrayBuffer`.

There are two ways to fix:

a) `oReq.responseType = "blob"`

OR

b) `var blob = new Blob([oReq.response])`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but check i have updated complete question with example

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to solve this using [Filereader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)? It looks like it might help in your situation